# UITableView: the proper way to display a separator for the last cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

The question is what's the right-most way to display a separator in the last cell in a table/section.

Basically this is what I am after.

[image]
This is from the native music app, which makes me think that it should be possible to achieve just by means of `UITableView`, they would not be using some private API for cell separators, right?

I know you can get away without using actual separators, but adding one pixel line in the bottom of the cell. But I'm not a fan of this approach because

1. When a cell is selected/highlighted **its** separator **and** the separator of the **previous cell** are automatically hidden (see the second screenshot with "You've got to be crazy" selected). And this is
   something I want UITableView to handle instead of doing myself if I use one-pixel line
   (which is especially handy when cell separators do not extend all
   the way to the edge of the table view, separators and selected cell background do not look nice together).
2. I would like to keep my cells as flat as possible for scrolling performance.

Also there is something in UITableView reference that makes me think that there is an easy way to get what I want:

> In iOS 7 and later, cell separators do not extend all the way to the
>   edge of the table view. This property sets the default inset for all
>   cells in the table, much like rowHeight sets the default height for
>   cells. **It is also used for managing the “extra” separators drawn at
>   the bottom of plain style tables.**

Does somebody know how exactly to use these “extra” separators drawn at the bottom of plain style tables? Because this is exactly what I need. 
I thought assigning `separatorInset`to the `UITableView`, not `UITableViewCell` would do the trick, but it does not, the last cell is still missing its separator.

Right now I only see one option: to have a custom section footer to mimic the separator for the last cell. And this is not good, especially if you want to have an actual section footer using `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` method.

Comment: So... let me see if I understand right. You want an separator for your last cell to be shown beneath it, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also would like it to have custom insets and to disappear nicely when the cell is selected.

Comment: Here's a great answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354801/4362465; it worked for me & I hope it helps you too :)

Answer (score 17):

This worked flawlessly for me to add a separator to the last cell. have fun!

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Comment: I had to remove the implementations for viewForFooterInSection and heightForFooterInSection and it worked.

Answer (score 14):

When you add headerView or footerView to your TableView, last separator line will disappear.

Example below will let you make workaround for showing separator on the last cell. The only thing you have to implement more is to make this separator disappearing after selecting cell, so behavior is the same like in the rest of cells.

For Swift **4.0**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let result = UIView()

    // recreate insets from existing ones in the table view
    let insets = tableView.separatorInset
    let width = tableView.bounds.width - insets.left - insets.right
    let sepFrame = CGRect(x: insets.left, y: -0.5, width: width, height: 0.5)

    // create layer with separator, setting color
    let sep = CALayer()
    sep.frame = sepFrame
    sep.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
    result.layer.addSublayer(sep)

    return result
}
```

Comment: @ironRoei I’m glad :)

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I just found something that works for me. In a few words: **give your UITableView a tableFooterView and set its frame's height to 0**. This makes an actual separator show, with the right insets.

In more details: if you are using the storyboard, drag a UIView to the bottom of your Table View (in the tree view on the left) so it shows just below Table View Cell, at the same hierarchical level. This creates a tableFooterView. Of course this can be done programmatically as well.

Then, in your UITableViewController's implementation:

```
UIView *footerView = self.tableView.tableFooterView;
CGRect footerFrame = footerView.frame;
footerFrame.size.height = 0;
[footerView setFrame:footerFrame];
```

Let me know if that works for you! It might also work for the first separator if you use a tableHeaderView instead, I haven't tried it though.

Comment: I simply returned a height of 0 in the heightForFooterInSection method.  This will show edge insets for all of the cells (even ones that are not populated).  For me this worked, but this would not be a viable solution for the poster of this question.

Comment: I believe this is the answer without doing any hackery stuff.  It works by giving me the separator for the last cell but remove the rest of empty cells.

Answer (score 5):

So here's a super simple solution in **Swift 4** which works:

Inside `override func viewDidLoad(){}`, I simply implemented this line of code:

```
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Hence it ensures that only the last cell gets the separator inset.

This worked perfectly for me, hope it does for you too!

Answer (score 3):

this will do exactly what you want .. even though the line will take the entire width of the cell:

in  `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: That's the problem, UIEdgeInsetsZero is not what I need. And they do have it working for separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0., 15., 0., 15.) in the native music, so there must be a way.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this if you are not using sections:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(insetLeftSide, 0, width - insetRightSide, 1)];
}
```

If you are using  sections implement the footer in each section as a one point View in the methods

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}
```

This will allow you to have a separator for your last cell which in fact is not a separator is a footer that you can play with it and make it look like a separator

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

I found this old issue, so I tried the same in Swift:

```
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.tableFooterView?.height = 0 // Maybe not necessary
```

But it lead to another problem (in my case). So I solved it differently. I added an extra cell at the end of this section, empty and with height equal to zero:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return previousNumberOfRows + 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return indexPath.row == previousNumberOfRows ? 0 : previousCellHeight
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      if indexPath.row == items.count {
        return UITableViewCell()
    } else {
       previousCellInitialization()
    }
```

This is a less concise solution, but works in more cases, if you have multiple sections, existing footer view(s)...

Comment: I believe this is the only way to get a bottom separator when you actually have a footer view. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found a workaround. Apple hides the last uitableviewcell separator and then displays it if you select the cell or if you call select and deselect on that cell.

So I taught the best is in `- (void)layoutSubviews`. The separator view is called `_separatorView` and it's a private property. Using the cell's selected / highlighted states you can come up with something like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Call super so the OS can do it's layout first
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Get the separator view
    UIView *separatorView = [self valueForKey:@"_separatorView"];
    // Make the custom inset
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.bounds.size.width, separatorView.frame.size.height);
    newFrame = CGRectInset(newFrame, 15.0, 0.0);
    [separatorView setFrame:newFrame];

    // Show or hide the bar based on cell state        
    if (!self.selected) {
        separatorView.hidden = NO;
    }
    if (self.isHighlighted) {
        separatorView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'd rather draw a one pixel line on the bottom of the self than use private API. But what you suggest does work, so I am up voting your answer although I am not accepting it since I am still hoping that someone will explain to me what *"It is also used for managing the “extra” separators drawn at the bottom of plain style tables"* means and hoe to use it in my case.

Comment: You could use layoutSubviews to watch the hidden property on that _separatorView object. I think that hiding it is "expected behaviour", unles it's not on screen.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8, if you have a plain style UITableView, and add a footer, the last separator is gone. However, you can easily recreate it by adding a custom separator view to the footer.

This example exactly mimics Today Widget separator style

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        //create footer view
        let result = UIView()
        result.frame.size.height = tableView.rowHeight

        //recreate last cell separator, which gets hidden by footer
        let sepFrame = CGRectMake(15, -0.5, tableView.frame.width, 0.5);
        let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: UIVibrancyEffect.notificationCenterVibrancyEffect())
        vibrancyEffectView.frame = sepFrame
        vibrancyEffectView.contentView.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor
        result.addSubview(vibrancyEffectView)
        return result
}
```

Comment: This really works, but for Swift 2.3 I wasn't able to use this line `let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: UIVibrancyEffect.notificationCenterVibrancyEffect())` so I replaced it with this one `let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight)))`

Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you add an empty footer then the tableview will remove all the remaining line separators (for non-existent cells) but will still include the separator for the last cell:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [UIView new]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the table view style "grouped" to add this line:

[image]

And furthermore it avoids sticking the last separator line to stick on the screen when scrolling out!

Answer (score 0):

Works in iOS 7.x and 8.x (put it in cellForRowAtIndexPath):

(PS substitute "max elements of your datasource" with your array datasource count)

```
 if (row == <max elements of your datasource>-1) {
     UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height-1, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];/// change size as you need.
     separatorLineView.tag = 666;
     separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 204.0/255.0 green: 204.0/255.0 blue: 204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
     UIView *separator = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:666];
     // case of orientation changed..
     if (separator.frame.size.width != cell.contentView.frame.size.width) {
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:666] removeFromSuperview];
        separator = nil;
     }
     if (separator==nil) [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely help. Working. 
but set separator "none" from attribute inspector.
Write following code in  **cellForRowAtIndexPath**  method

```
if(indexPath.row==arrData.count-1){
 UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,           
 cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0,      
 cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];

    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me:

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0.35)];
footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
CGRect frame = footerView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 15;
frame.size.width = frame.size.width - 15;
UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[blackView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
blackView.alpha = 0.25;
[footerView addSubview:blackView];
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

Hope it works for you too.