# Wrong UITableView separator color on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm setting `UITableView` separator color this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.1f];
}
```

And **SOMETIMES** on **iOS7** my table view separators look different (cells with data and empty cells separators have different alpha I guess), look at attached image:
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @santhu The first two separators are clearly darker than those which separate blank cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove all cell's separator which has empty  content then use following line of code.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

in `viewDidLoad` method.

**Other wise** set `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` and set your custom `UIImage`for separator.

**EX:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell"; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        .
        . // your other code.
        .
        UIImageView *imgLine = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imgLine.tag = 101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: imgLine];
     }

        .
        . // your other code.
        .

     UIImageView *imgLine = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
     imgLine.frame =  CGRectMake(5, 69, 310, 1);
     imgLine.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"queTblLine.png"];

     return cell;
}
```

And don't forget to set `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

**EDITE :**
Not sure but might be helpful in your case:

set   `self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`

Get [From question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767543/uitableview-the-proper-way-to-display-a-separator-for-the-last-cell)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to "remove" empty cells, I want empty cells to have the same separator colors as those with data.

Comment: Then you might be use of my other suggestion which is also best and easy for you. :)

Comment: How to set an UIImage for table separator? Add an UIImageView as cell subview?

Comment: Used the last option (i.e [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19769234/2298998)), and seems to work fine. Thanks.

Comment: +1! set `self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` and work like a charm!!! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Swap the order of the two statements. Set the color first, then the inset:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this visually in storyboard or nib/xib

Put UIImageView at bottom edge of cell and you can set image as per your requirement

**STEP 1: Set divider as per image**

[image: Set divider as per image]

**STEP 2: Set Separator style to none**

[image: Set Separator style to none]

Answer (score 1):

You can set it programatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[UITableView appearance] setSeparatorColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}
```